# Redimensionar imagem com PHP mantendo proporção

Tags: php, imagem

Eu gostaria de redimensionar imagens pela proporção a partir de um link remoto utilizando PHP. Isso é possível?

Tipo:

> http://site.net/imagem.jpg

para

> http://exemplo.com/resize.php?img=http://site.net/imagem.jpg&width=100

Nota: No caso, os 2 endereços pertenceria a mim. Sem roubo de imagens.

Comment: Tente colocar as imagens mesmo, senão para futuras pesquisas ninguém saberá a que se refere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solução com a biblioteca GD

Uma coisa muito comum nas instalações padrão do PHP é a biblioteca **GD** estar integrada na distribuição. Se for este o seu caso, basta usar a função [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresampled.php) para gerar uma imagem com novo tamanho.

```php
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $img_destino, resource $img_origem,
                            int $x_destino , int $y_destino,
                            int $x_origem, int $y_origem,
                            int $largura_destino, int $altura_destino,
                            int $largura_origem, int $altura_origem )
```

Exemplo de uso, vindo da página do php linkada, mas adaptado para a pergunta:

```
<?php
   // O arquivo. Dependendo da configuração do PHP pode ser uma URL.
   $filename = 'original.jpg';
   //$filename = 'http://exemplo.com/original.jpg';

   // Largura e altura máximos (máximo, pois como é proporcional, o resultado varia)
   // No caso da pergunta, basta usar $_GET['width'] e $_GET['height'], ou só
   // $_GET['width'] e adaptar a fórmula de proporção abaixo.
   $width = 200;
   $height = 200;

   // Obtendo o tamanho original
   list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

   // Calculando a proporção
   $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

   if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
      $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
   } else {
      $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
   }

   // O resize propriamente dito. Na verdade, estamos gerando uma nova imagem.
   $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
   imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

   // Gerando a imagem de saída para ver no browser, qualidade 75%:
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   imagejpeg($image_p, null, 75);

   // Ou, se preferir, Salvando a imagem em arquivo:
   imagejpeg($image_p, 'nova.jpg', 75);
?>
```

> Note que no exemplo estamos abrindo a imagem de um arquivo, mas a função também serve para abrir de uma URL, apenas alterando o caminho fornecido. Veja a documentação da diretiva **[allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)** do PHP, que controla este comportamento.

### Se preferir recortar a imagem

O código acima faz com que a imagem caiba na medida especificada, deixando "sobra" no lado menor. Se preferir que fique ocupando a área total, basta alterar com o trecho a seguir:

```
// inverte a comparação e calcula o offset
if ($width/$height < $ratio_orig) { 
   $dif_w = $height*$ratio_orig/2-$height;
   $dif_h = 0;
} else {
   $dif_w = 0;
   $dif_h = $width/$ratio_orig/2-$width;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
// e ajusta a origem
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, -$dif_w, -$dif_h, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
```

Comment: Explicação excelente! Uma estrela a mais para você!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) para redimensionar a imagem.

Por exemplo:

```
$path = $_GET['img'];

// faça as verificações de validade da imagem...

$image = WideImage::load($path);

// scala:
$width = $_GET['width']; // verifique se é válido.

if($width > 0)
{
    $scale = $image->getWidth()/$width;
}
else
{
    //tratar caso de largura inválida.
}

// Calcula a altura equivalente a largura passada.
$height = $image->getHeight() * $scale;

$resizedImage = $image->resize($width, $height);

// Daqui para frente você faz o que deve fazer com sua imagem.
// Por exemplo:
$resizedImage->saveToFile('imagem_redimencionada.jpg');
// Ou:
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$resizedImage->output('jpg', 100); // Onde 100 é a qualidade em %
```