# Como definir tamanho padrão de uma imagem PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de definir a altura, e a largura padrão no php, eu vi algumas formas, mas eu usava uma classe externa, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de usar a biblioteca GD...

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('imgs/bg.jpg');
$tamanho = imagesx($dest);
$width = 594;
$height = 387;

$src = imagecreatefrompng('imgs/textura.png');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, -30, -50, 0, 0, 700, 500, 50); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: Aqui eu postei uma resposta que mostra como acertar o tamanho de uma imagem usando a biblioteca GD http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9757/70 - Pelos comments você pode entender o que cada parte do código faz.

Comment: Ainda ta meio complicado, eu ja tenho um código pronto, vou editar a pergunta pra melhorar, esse meu código ele coloca uma imagem em cima de outra, mas quando a imagem é menor de 500px a que fica em cima não centraliza, a solução seria fazer um redimensionamento ou usar if para diferentes tamanhos...

Comment: pra centralizar é só fazer a conta: `margem esquerda = ( largura da maior - largura da menor ) / 2`, e a mesma coisa para a margem de cima.

Comment: Não entendi o que você disse, a margem eu defini nessa linha

>imagecopymerge($dest, $src, -30, -50, 0, 0, 700, 500, 50); 

Ali no "-30"

Comment: Sei disso O que precisa é trocar o -30 e o -50 pela fórmula que eu postei. Para ver como pegar estas variáveis, basta dar uma lida naquela resposta que eu fiz o link.

Comment: Quando você diz "tamanho da maior" e "Tamanho da menor" é o tamamho da maior imagem/menor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer pode ser resolvido desta forma:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('imgs/bg.jpg');
$tamanho = imagesx($dest);
$width = 594;
$height = 387;

$larguraPadrao = 700;
$alturaPadrao  = 500;

$centro_x      = ceil( ( $larguraPadrao-$width ) / 2 );
$centro_y      = ceil( ( $alturaPadrao-$height ) / 2 );

$src = imagecreatefrompng('imgs/textura.png');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, $centro_x, $centro_y, 0, 0, $larguraPadrao, $alturaPadrao, 50);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```