# Criar miniaturas de várias imagens em uma pasta de uma só vez

Tags: php, imagem, thumbnail

Boa tarde pessoal, estou precisando criar miniaturas de todas as imagens contidas em uma determinada pasta e salvar dentro de uma pasta thumb

Ex:

Pasta "fotos" com várias imagens JPG
Se a pasta thumb não existir o código deve criar e salvar dentro dessa pasta as miniaturas das imagens contidas em fotos com o mesmo nome.

fotos/imagem1.jpg <<< imagem normal
fotos/thumb/imagem1.jpg <<< miniatura

Só encontrei códigos que fazem esse redimensionamento durante o upload das imagens, mas esse não é o caso, visto que as imagens já estão no servidor.
Alguém poderia me auxiliar? Obrigado

Comment: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9754/redimensionar-imagem-com-php-mantendo-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Obrigado pela mensagem, mas não quero usar a classe GD pois ela cria a miniatura apenas virtualmente, quero é criar uma nova imagem e salvar em outra pasta.

Comment: Com a GD você também pode salvar em arquivo, não apenas enviar para o browser. O link do primeiro comentário inclusive tem um exemplo disso na resposta.

Comment: @JúlioNeto poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso pegando todas as imagens de uma pasta? No exemplo que tem lá usa apenas 1 imagem. No caso eu preciso reduzir 200, 300 imagens.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira Cara infelizmente, não vou ter tempo agora de escrever uma resposta mais completa, mas você pode usar as funções opendir e readdir para conseguir uma lista de todos os arquivos de uma pasta e executar o código acima pra cada um.