# Compactação de imagem sem alterar o formato do conteudo (png, jpeg, gif, webp)

Tags: php, processamento-de-imagens

A diferença dessa pergunta para as duplicadas: manter o formato do conteúdo (png, jpeg, gif, webp), a fim de não prejudicar imagens com camadas, transparência, etc. As outras não tem.

---

Tenho um **script de upload de arquivo**, onde salvo o arquivo em uma pasta, e gravo no banco de dados o endereço:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['anexo']['name']) && ($fass[0]['status'] != 'C' && $fass[0]['status'] != 'F'))
{
        $arqNome = $_FILES['anexo']['name'];
        $extpat  = pathinfo($_FILES['anexo']['name']);
        $ext     = $extpat['extension'];

        $uploaddir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sys/files/';
        $uploadfile = $tId . '-' . time();
        $uploadatt  = $uploaddir . $uploadfile . '.' . $ext;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['anx']['tmp_name'], $uploadatt)) 
        {
            $dir = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $uploaddir);
            $arq = $uploadfile;
            $att = $arq . '.' . $ext; // $dir

            if ($attc -> attachments($tId,$arqNome,$att,$solicitante))
            {
                header('location:../t_vis.php?id='. $tId);
            }
        }
}
```

---

Estive verificando, e tem anexos de **imagens** que estão **muito grandes**.

Gostaria de "compactar/diminuir" a imagem, como por exemplo o Whatsapp faz, mas claro, sem perder a qualidade da imagem, mantendo tipo de arquivo (jpg, png, etc), assim não "estraga" a imagem original com a perda de camadas, transparência, etc.

- Existem funções nativas para esta finalidade?
- Existem bibliotecas?
- Existem outras formas?

Comment: compactar/diminuir a imagem sem perder a qualidade da imagem e sem trocar o tipo é impossível... alguma informação precisa ser removida ou diminuída, como informações de meta dados do arquivo (local de foto, comentários, etc), resolução e número de cores, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta você usar para cada imagem as funções para cada formato:

### Para PNG

- [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
- [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

### Para JPEG

- [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)
- [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

### Para GIF

- [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)
- [`imagegif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)

### Para WEBP (requer PHP 5.4+)

- [`imagecreatefromwebp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php)
- [`imagewebp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php)

---

Existem outros formatos claro, como BMP e WBMP, mas são formatos nada bons para trabalhar com WEB, já que geralmente não tem compressão o que torna uma imagem simples bem pesada.

---

### Trabalhando sem perder transparência

Usar `imagecreatefrompng` pode ocasionar perda da transparencia, então para evitar a perda use:

```
imagealphablending (resource $image , true);
imagesavealpha (resource $image , true);
```

---

### Um exemplo de código para reduzir imagens com PHP em diferentes formatos

Seguindo o exemplo de calculo da resposta do [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9757/3635):

```
<?php
function image_resize($path, $width = 200, $height = 200, $save = null, $quality = 100)
{
    $details = getimagesize($path);

    if (!$details) {
        trigger_error('Imagem inválida');
        return false;
    }

    $width_orig = $details[0];
    $height_orig = $details[1];

    // Calculando a proporção
    $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;

    if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
    }

    if (is_string($save) === false) {
        $save = null;
        header('Content-Type: ' . $details['mime']);
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    switch ($details['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            break; 
        case 'image/gif': 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($path);
            break; 
        case 'image/png': 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
            break;
        case 'image/webp': 
            $image = imagecreatefromwebp($path);
            break;
        default:
            trigger_error('Formato não suportado');
            $image_p = null;
            return false;
    }

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

    if ( in_array($details['mime'], array('image/png', 'image/webp')) ) {
        imagealphablending($image_p, true);
        imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
    }

    switch ($details['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($image_p, $save, $quality);
            break; 
        case 'image/gif': 
            imagegif($image_p, $save);
            break; 
        case 'image/png': 
            imagepng($image_p, $save, $quality);
            break;
        case 'image/webp': 
            imagewebp($image_p, $save, $quality);
            break;
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso para copiar uma imagem JPEG para uma nova menor:

```
image_resize('bar.jpg', 200, 200, 'bar_1.jpg');
```

Para sobrescrever uma imagem basta usar o mesmo nome:

```
image_resize('bar.jpg', 200, 200, 'bar.jpg');
```

O primeiro `200` seria a largura máxima, e o segundo é a altura máxima.

Comment: No caso do do resize, teria como manter a proporção da imagem ao invés de definir altura e largura e arriscar distorcer? Na propriedade "qualidade", ele faz referência a o que? Porque, por exemplo, tenho uma imagem que já estaria em qualidade baixa, então não poderia reduzir mais. Isso seria em pixels (resolução)? O que ele considera?

Comment: @RBZ é justamente isso que o $width e $height fazem, eles são os tamanhos máximos, ou seja ao diminuir mantem a proporção (ratio), a não ser o que o código esteja com algum BUG, o $quality pode ser mantido em 100 se a imagem já estiver ruim, a GD do PHP não é tão boa para trabalhar com checagem da qualidade atual, existem softwares especializados para isso, mas já não seria com PHP, seria com terminal + exec(); do PHP

Comment: Eita, desculpa, não entendi... Vamos supor que a imagem é 800x600, mas eu "não sei" disso, até porque irão fazer upload de vários formatos e tamanhos certo!? Se eu travar um width e height vai distorcer porque não são todas iguais. Ou eu não sou obrigado setá-los? Quanto a qualidade, a mesma coisa. Terei imagens, por ex., UHD e HD, se a qualidade estiver 90, irá reduzi-las ou a qualidade reconhece um padrão, tipo, qualidade 90 é resolução HD, 95 FullHD, etc

Comment: Ou seria qualidade proporcional. Por ex.: 90 seria 90% da qualidade atual. Aí considerando a forma que ele trabalha com a qualidade, eu poderia trabalhar também com o `tamanho` do arquivo, assim arquivo de até 1mb, uso qualidade 90, acima disso, uso 85, e assim vai...

Comment: @RBZ sim, da atual, mas o sistema de compressão do GD não é inteligente,  não tem muito o que fazer, eu recomendo usar entre 92 e 95 para JPEG, para outros formatos pode variar muito, ainda mais PNG.

Comment: @RBZ qual a largura e altura máxima deseja que a imagem tenha?

Comment: Meu foco seria no tamanho de arquivo, por isso nem precisaria mexer na proporção. Estou vendo que a ideia seria verificar primeiro o tamanho, e ver a necessidade de redução, depois o tipo (extenção) para manter num intervalo de qualidade aceitável. Mas para entender a proporção... se eu setar apenas uma medida (width ou height), a outra ele irá fazer proporcional?

Comment: @RBZ use o getimagesize e veja se é menor ou maior, se for maior executa, se bem que dá para implementar no código.

Comment: @RBZ vou mudar o código para que quando a imagem for igual ou menor que a altura e largura mencionadas nos argumentos ele faça apenas o imagecopyresampled, não há garantias que o GD vai diminuir o tamanho da foto, como eu já disse antes, mas em casos de imagens de cameras digitais talvez limpe muita coisa

Comment: Meu medo é perder proporção e distorcer. Você já testou alguma vez se ele mantém proporção? Se informar só o width ou height ele irá fazer o outro proporcional?